# Equation subscript help

Tags: beamer, equations

I am using equation mode in beamer slides and I am having difficulty getting my equation to look like the following picture below.

[image]

I use this code and this is what the output is. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
arg min_{{w^i_j}_j
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first image in your question is not really a good example. It uses math mode for multi-letter words, you can see the messed up kerning between e.g. `C` and `o`.

Instead you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\[
\argmin_{\{w^i_j\}_{j\in \text{ControlGroup}}} 
\]
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you prefer serif math font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\[
\argmin_{\{w^i_j\}_{j\in \text{ControlGroup}}} 
\]
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]